# PySpark: error when calling 'count' function

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to run a simple example with pyspark. Here is the code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App")
data = sc.textFile("/opt/HistorCommande.csv")
         .map(lambda line: line.split(","))
         .map(lambda record:(record[0], record[1], record[2]))
NbCommande = data.count()
print("Nb de commandes: %d" % NbCommande)
```

However, when I run this piece of code (cmd: ./bin/spark-submit /opt/test.py), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/test.py", line 6, in <module>
     NbCommande = data.count()
  File "/opt/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1041, in count
  File "/opt/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1032, in sum
  File "/opt/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 906, in fold
  File "/opt/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 809, in collect
  File "/opt/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
  py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError
```

I don't know what it means and therefore, I can't sove it. I tried the wordCound example and I got the sam error.

If anyone has an idea about how to solve this issue, I would be very thankful.

Comment: Does this stacktrace have any continuation with JVM exception details?

Comment: I am using java 1.8. Actually, I achieved to run my projects in java with the same Spark project and I didn't get any error. I wanted to try pyspark but I got this error..

Comment: Do you get any Java exception after last `py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError` line?

Comment: It doesn't give any other line ...

Comment: Strange... Does the `spark-submit` print any other lines to stdout or stderr? Can you paste complete output?